# Create new variable based on the value of several other variables

Tags: r

So I have a data set that has multiple variables that I want to use to create a new variable. I have seen other questions like this that use the ifelse statement, but this would be extremely insufficient since the new variable is based on 32 other variables. The variables are coded with values of 1, 2, 3, or NA, and I am wanting the new variable to be coded as 1 if 2 or more of the 32 variables take on a value of 1, and 2 otherwise. Here is a small example of what I have been trying to do.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, v1 = c(1,2,2,2,3,NA,2,2,2,2), v2 = c(2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2), 
             v3 = c(1,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2), v4 = c(2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3))
```

and the result I am looking for is this:

```
   id v1 v2 v3 v4 new
1   1  1  2  1  2   1
2   2  2  2  2  2   2
3   3  2  2  2  2   2
4   4  2  2  2  2   2
5   5  3  2  2  2   1
6   6 NA  1  3  1   2
7   7  2  2  2  2   2
8   8  2  1  2  2   2
9   9  2  2  2  2   2
10 10  2  2  2  3   2
```

I have also tried using rowSums within the if else statement, but with the missing values this doesn't work for all observations unless I recode the NAs to another value which I want to avoid doing, and besides that I feel like there would be a much more efficient way of doing this.

I feel like it is likely that this question has been answered before, but I couldn't find anything on it. So help or direction to a previous answer would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at `?rowSums`, you should see that you can set `na.rm = TRUE` to exclude missing values.

Comment: Row 5 doesn't seem right. There are no 1's at all but it gets assigned a 1. I think you got rows 5 and 6 switched

Comment: `rowSums(df[-1]==1,na.rm=TRUE) >= 2` or similar I reckon.

Comment: `ifelse(rowSums(df[-1] == 1, na.rm = TRUE) >= 2, 1, 2)` seems right. I'm tempted to close as typo?  Seems like OP just needed to look at `?rowSums` to see it has the `na.rm` argument.

Comment: Sorry, the row 5 and row 6 was a mix up. I just typed this out to give an idea of what I was looking at. I was trying to use rowSums by adding up the values of all the variables (so rowSums <= 72 (which is 2 rows with one and all others with 2)). I didn't realize that you could have rowSums count the number of occurrences of a condition, so this has worked very nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you were very close to getting your desired output, but you were probably missing the `na.rm = TRUE` argument as part of your `rowSums()` call. This will remove any NAs before `rowSums` does its calculations.

Anyway, using your data frame from above, I created a new variable that counts the number of times 1 appears across the variables, while ignoring NA values. Note that I've subsetted the data to exclude the `id` column:

```
df$count <- rowSums(df[-1] == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Then I created another variable using an ifelse statement that returns a 1 if the count is 2 or more or a 2 otherwise.

```
df$var <- ifelse(df$count >= 2, 1, 2)
```

The returned output:

```
  id v1 v2 v3 v4 count var
1   1  1  2  1  2     2   1
2   2  2  2  2  2     0   2
3   3  2  2  2  2     0   2
4   4  2  2  2  2     0   2
5   5  3  2  2  2     0   2
6   6 NA  1  3  1     2   1
7   7  2  2  2  2     0   2
8   8  2  1  2  2     1   2
9   9  2  2  2  2     0   2
10 10  2  2  2  3     0   2
```

**UPDATE / EDIT:** As mentioned by Gregor in the comments, you can also just wrap the `rowSums` function in the `ifelse` statement for one line of code.

Comment: This worked nicely. As I mentioned in the comment above, I didn't realize that you could have rowSums count the number of occurrences of a condition. Thank you.